# fullpage JS: Anchors in mobile viewport not navigating to the sections exactly

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am using FullPage JS to display a few sections. On the desktop, anchors navigating to the sections perfectly.

Coming to the mobile I'm having fixed header, restricting height of the sections using **fp-auto-height-responsive** and restricting autoscroll with **responsiveWidth**. In this case the anchor links not navigating to the exact section position. Is there any solution to fix this issue or I'm missing any property to add? I have gone through the documentation but I didn't find any solution.

Here is my JS:

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    //options here
    autoScrolling:true,
    navigation:true,
    anchors:['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6'],
    navigationTooltips:['S1','S2','S3','S4','S5','S6'],
    showActiveTooltip:true,
    scrollingSpeed:700,
    responsiveWidth: 991,
    menu:'#nav',
});
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine. Check out the reproduction here: https://jsfiddle.net/nqxobar9/

Comment: Make sure to use the latest version 3.1.1 just in case.

Comment: Hey @Alvaro thanks for the quick reply. Yes I'm using the latest version. Can you please see this code pen [codepen link](https://codepen.io/Wazeed_M/pen/MWpWKPW). Here I have created a demo with fixed header. Now It is anchoring to the section but can we remove header height when we reach to that particular section? And In mobile, while scrolling the anchors in URL not getting changed. I know It is happening because I have disabled auto scroll using responsiveWidth:991px. But Is it possible to track the URL anchors when auto scroll is disabled?

Comment: Anchors will update. See [the demo here](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html#firstPage) when using `autoScrolling:false` which is the equivalent to responsive mode.